# Galois theory on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, zeta-functions

Context: Let $\mathbb{F}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$ for $q$ prime. We know that $\mathbb{F}(t)$ for $t$ transcendental is the function field of the projective line $\mathbb{P}^{1}(\mathbb{F})$. Assume that $K$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{F}(t)$. Denote by $C$ the corresponding projective curve of $K$.

> What is meant by the group of automorphisms of $C/\mathbb{P}^{1}(\mathbb{F})$?
>
> Can you give me literature reference for the topic Galois Theory on Curves and covering maps (some more key words: Galois covering, groups which acts on the fiber of a covering map, ramified etc.)?
> As simple as possible (I am a non-expert!)

I read the subchapter about Riemann hypothesis for curves over finite fields in C. Moreno's book (google book link, page 60-61 [C. Moreno, Curve over finite fields](http://books.google.ch/books?id=L8YnlDqV3MoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Some implicit indication of the author: In some other place, the author evaluates the Frobenius automorphism ($\phi(x):=x^q$ for $x \in K$) at points of $C$. RigorouslyIs this is impossible, is it in some way possible, if do some identification of $K$ and $C$?

Comment: It's equivalent to the group of automorphisms of $K$ as an extension of $\mathbb{F}(t)$.

Comment: I did a mistake (I correct it). The question is: What is meant by the group of automorphisms of $C/\mathbb{P}^{1}(\mathbb{F})$?.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Is that by definiton of this group? How does the identification look like exactly? Do we identify points with their valuation rings? Sometimes the author did this.
Or can we really define "automorphisms" on the points of the curves, where the morphism are the morphism of the category of varieties? I don't know, if the last question makes sense ;).

Comment: Please note that I add a request for reference.

Answer (score 3):

In the amazing (as Mumford calls it) correspondence between  algebra and geometry in the question, a finite extension $\mathbb F(t)\subset K$ (not necessary normal nor separable) corresponds to a smooth projective curve **plus** a finite morphism $\pi:C\to \mathbb P^1_\mathbb F$.
The group of automorphisms of $C/\mathbb P^1_\mathbb F$ is then simply the group of automorphisms $f:C\to C$ commuting with $f$ i.e. such that $\pi \circ f=\pi$.
As Qiaochu comments, this group (of very geometric nature) is isomorphic to the group (of very algebraic nature)  of automorphisms $Aut(K/\mathbb F(t))$ .
(Do not write  that last  group  $Gal(K/\mathbb F(t))$ because the extension $\mathbb F(t)\subset K$ needn't be Galois)
And to answer your last question: this has nothing to do with Frobenius.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the correspondence between ${\text{irreducible projective curve with rational maps}}$ and ${\text{finite extension of }k(x) \text{with k-algebra-homomorphisms}}$ (Probably an anti-equivalence of categories). How this finite morphism $\pi : C \to \mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{F}}$ look like exactly?

Comment: Please note that I didn't meant that Frobenius automorphism does something to do with this $Aut(C/\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{F}}$. But in the book, the Frobenius automorphism is evaluated at points of the curve, which makes (by strictly reasoning) no sense, because by definition the Frobenius automorphism is a map between $K$, where $K$ is the function field of $C$. Some (hidden) identification with points on $C$ and element in $K$ is done, but which one exactly?

Comment: @bjn: Don't forget the classical formulation of algebraic geometry where you work in things like spaces of nonzero $(n+1)$-tuples of points. Also, don't forget that every automorphism of $F$ defines an automorphism of polynomial rings over $F$ by fixing the variables and just transforming the coefficients.

Comment: Is $\pi$ the canonical projection in one variable, i.e. $\pi(x,y)=x$? This would be corresponding map between $C$ and $\mathbb{P}_{F}^{1}$ of the canonical inclusion $i: \mathbb{F}(t) \to K, x \mapsto x$?